# Python "while true" loop does NOT end (using Python Tweepy)

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

The following code seems to be mostly "working". Meaning that it scrapes all the tweets from Twitter API for a specified day. Though it seems the while True loop never breaks and I don't see the expected "Finished!!" string even through the csv file is complete.

```
import tweepy
import time
import csv

ckey = "xxx"
csecret = "xxx"
atoken = "xxx-xxx"
asecret = "xxx"

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,
    'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

startSince = '2014-10-03'
endUntil = '2014-10-04'
suffix = '_03OCT2014.csv'

searchTerms = 'xyz'

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerms,
    since=startSince, until=endUntil).items()

while True:
    try: 
        for tweet in tweets:

            placeHolder = []
            placeHolder.append(tweet.author.name.encode('utf8'))
            placeHolder.append(tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8'))
            placeHolder.append(tweet.created_at)

            prefix = 'TweetData_xyz'
            wholeFileName = prefix + suffix     
            with open(wholeFileName, "ab") as f:
                writeFile = csv.writer(f)
                writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)

    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*15)
        continue

    except IOError:
        time.sleep(60*5)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break

print "Finished!!!"
```

Comment: If it never creates an exception it will never end the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StopIteration` is never raised in your code. The `for` statement would catch it if it were raised by `tweepy.Cursor().items()`, it would *not* propagate further.

Just break out if the `for` loop ends:

```
while True:
    try:
        for tweet in tweets:
            # do stuff

        # completed iterating successfully
        break
```

and remove the `except StopIteration:` handler altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You code has no exit condition.
It seems you don;t want to exit that loop if you got an error thrown. So I assume that when you reach end ob your while body you would like to exit, yes?

```
def process_tweet(tweet):

    placeHolder = []
    placeHolder.append(tweet.author.name.encode('utf8'))
    placeHolder.append(tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8'))
    placeHolder.append(tweet.created_at)

    prefix = 'TweetData_xyz'
    wholeFileName = prefix + suffix     
    with open(wholeFileName, "ab") as f:
       writeFile = csv.writer(f)
       writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)

while True:
    try: 
        for tweet in tweets:
            process_tweet(tweet)
        break
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60*15)
        continue

    except IOError:
        time.sleep(60*5)
        continue

    except StopIteration:
        break

print "Finished!!!"
```